# Powercli Script to count the ESXI-Host and its Vm's on each clusters

Tags: vmware, powercli

I am trying create a on-liner script which gives an outputs of Hosts and vm's counts in a vcenter cluster like as below.

[image]

**Just using a sample oneliner**
*Get-VMHost | Select @{N=“Cl“;E={Get-Cluster -VMHost $_}} Name, @{N=“NumVM“;E={($_ | Get-VM).Count}} | Sort Cluster, Name*

any Ideas?? Thanks in advance

Regards,
Subash.

Answer (score 2):

A bit long for a one-liner, but

```
get-cluster | select @{n="cluster";e={$_.name}}, @{n="hosts";e={($_ | get-vmhost).count}}, @{n="vms";e={($_ | get-vm).count}} | sort cluster | ft -auto
```